# View is being rendered as html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that is being renders the html code of the page.
The view is being called by the following code.

```
IController errorController = new ErrorsController();
Response.StatusCode = 404;
errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
```

If I enter the url for the page directly, it works fine.
    Views/Errors/http404

How can I get it to render from the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using MVC 4.5. I just used the following code to render the page:

```
httpContext.Server.TransferRequest("/Error/404Page", true);
```

It's better than a Redirect.